# Test whether a class level method change attribute of another class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

In the Ruby application I have a class(Resque Job) that has method that affect the values of a different class when called with the id of the latter class.

```
class ResqueKlass 
   def self.perform(id)
     obj = EditKlass.find(id)
     obj.update(value: 0)
   end
end
```

I want to use rspec to test that this value was indeed changed within method

```
describe 'Something' do
let(:obj){FactoryGirl.create(:editklass)}

  scenario 'Change obj value' do
     ResqueKlass.perform(obj.id)
     expect(obj.value).to eq(0)
  end
end
```

This test fails where it expect 0 it get the value that was set in the factory girl.

I have also tried not using factory girl create 'obj' with let but that still does not work. I have placed bindings in the ResqueKlass perform method and i can see that the value is being updated.

PS please bear in mind that i am new to Ruby and rspec. These are not the exact classes that i am working with, the reason for that is the actual classes contain some sensitive data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens, because you do not reload that record and therefore your obj still shows the old version.

Try reloading the obj with `obj.reload`:

```
describe 'Something' do
  let(:obj){FactoryGirl.create(:editklass)}

  scenario 'Change obj value' do
     ResqueKlass.perform(obj.id)
     expect(obj.reload.value).to eq(0)
  end
end
```